# Euler's theorem to validate prime numbers shows non-primes as valid

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

I have noticed whispers regarding the notion of using Euler's Theorem to verify if a number is prime or not.

Typically, it is written as `6n +/- 1`  (plus or minus), and [this site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eulers6nPlus1Theorem.html) has it marked as `6n + 1` only.

When I went to test this, I found numbers such as "143" showed incorrectly as being prime due to :

### 143 - not a prime

```
6n + 1 = 143
6n = 143 - 1
n = 142 / 6
n = 23.666~7

6n - 1 = 143
6n = 143 + 1
n = 144 / 6
n = 24
```

### 149 - prime

```
6n + 1 = 149
6n = 149 - 1
n = 148 / 6
n = 24.666~7

6n - 1 = 149
6n = 149 + 1
n = 150 / 6
n = 25
```

If you notice both pass Euler's test under the evaluation of `6n-1`.  Am I oversimplifying Euler's theorem as used in so called prime verification, or is it just broken for this purpose ?

Is the only real way to validate primes reliably to use the sieve of Eratosthenes ?  Or is there another method, or am I just not understanding what appears to be a very simple theorem ?

Comment: You have totally misunderstood Euler's Theorem. It is not a method to "verify if a number is prime or not." It says something about primes of the form $6n+1$. It is another (simple) fact that every prime (other than 2 or 3) has either remainder 5 or 1 when divided by 6, which means that every prime can be written $6n\pm1$. In no way does that imply the converse: just because a number can be written $6n\pm1$ doesn't mean it's prime.

Comment: @symplectomorphic - serves me right for watching youtube videos and letting that overwrite the math portion of my brain.  XD.  I just wanted to make sure before I tossed it as a "primality" test, that it was actually invalid for this purpose and that I was doing the math right (aka, not overlooking something in it's implementation that would cause it to fail).  It isn't a primality test.  Thank you for confirming that :)

Comment: Others have addressed the link. "Is the only real way to validate primes reliably to use the sieve of Eratosthenes?"  SoE is a great way to *generate* primes.  It's not a primality test (though some implementations of some tests use it internally).  There are a large number of compositeness tests and primality tests, each with different tradeoffs.  I recommend Crandall and Pomerance, either buying a copy or perusing the online version.  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.132.7115

Comment: @DanaJ - thank you.  Following the breadcrumb to research further.  I do find primes to be a very fun topic as there is clearly a pattern to their distribution.  My love for puzzles won't let me let this go. I have read several theories some abstract like [this one](http://phys.org/news/2009-05-pattern-prime.html) where others are nothing more than something anomalous like `6n+/-1`. Unfortunately, for it to be a proof, it needs to work 100% of the time.  If you can validate, then you should be able to reverse it to generate. If you can't, then the method is wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wrote has very little to do with any primality test I've ever heard of.  You seem to be just verifying that your number can be written as $6n \pm 1$.  If you're talking about Euler's $6n+1$ theorem, what that says is that any prime of the form $6n+1$ can be written as $x^2 + 3 y^2$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.  But that's not a primality test either: there are lots of composite numbers of the form $x^2 + 3 y^2$.

A primality test associated with the name Euler is: if $b$ is a positive integer and $n$ is an odd prime that does not divide $b$, 
$b^{(n-1)/2} \equiv \pm 1 \mod n$.
That's a necessary condition but not sufficient: a composite $n$ with this property for a given $b$ is called an [Euler pseudoprime to base $b$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerPseudoprime.html).

Comment: Thank you for confirming Euler's theorem is not valid as a primality test.  Was noticing the composite issue after running some tests.  It looked too easy from the beginning, but I figured I would write the code (before using the math part of my brain), where I noticed something was off -- very off.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking something.